# Redirect Angular2 route to server route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, ecmascript-6

**What specific changes need to be made to [the Angular2 sample app at this GitHub link](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/) in order for user clicks on the `login` route to be redirected directly to the node.js server's `/login` route?**

I have carefully dissected the app, and see that [`boot.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/boot.js) gets its routes from [`app.routes.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/core/app.routes.js), which in turn delegates handling of the `login` route to [`login.component.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/auth/components/login/login.component.js).  Similarly, the node.js `/login` route is handled on the server by [`router.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/router.js).

My understanding is that the Angular2 changes would need to be made in [`login.component.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/auth/components/login/login.component.js), so that the `login.template.html` never gets served, and so that whatever event is triggered by the user click on the Angular `login` route gets handled with a redirect to the server `/login` route.  Is this true?  If so, how do I change [`login.component.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/auth/components/login/login.component.js) as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  directives: //???
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(router: Router) {
    this._router = router;
    //what else goes here???
  }
}
```

For these purposes, the node.js [`router.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/router.js) route can become:

```
router.post('/login', function*() {
    console.log('Inside Node.js router.js /login route!');
});
```

---

**A Partial Solution:**

---

In an attempt to follow @soyuka's suggestion, I added the following method to [`menu.component.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/core/components/menu/menu.component.js):

```
goToNodeLogin() {
  window.location.href='/login';
}
```

And then I added the following to [`menu.template.html`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/core/components/menu/menu.template.html):

```
<li><a (click)="goToNodeLogin()">Go to Node.js /login route</a></li>
```

And I added the following **GET** handler to the Node.js server's `router.js`:

```
router.get('/login', function*() {
  console.log('You made it to Node.js /login route!');
});
```

**The server route gets triggered and prints the console output when the user clicks the link.  But the browser gives a 404 error, and the link is not part of the Angular2 `login` route (or any other route).**

What else needs to be changed in order for the Angular `login` route to manage this call to the server?

Comment: window.location = '/login'

Comment: @soyuka I tried your suggestion, and added the results to the end of the OP.  What am I doing wrong?